# Can µTorrent torrents start automatically at top of queue?

Tags: bittorrent, utorrent

Can I make `Add to top of queue` default to true ([image: tickbox default to marked]) in µTorrent's *Add New Torrent* popup window?

[image: utorrent download popup]